exclude files from iCloud backup
I have a bug on my hands where icons, etc are being backed up to iCloud backup.
My first knee jerk reaction was that it's in the documents directory class but they are properly stowed in the NSCachesDirectory stowage class.
Is there anything else to check besides
[url getResourceValue:&isExcludedFromBackup forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];

on the directory that contains them?
I vaguely remember there was a mechanism to set (&verify?) a backup exclusion flag per file in the earlier version of iOS, but, somehow, that does not pop up in google search...
Thanks!
